# How do I test a function inside a component by using jest?

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a unit testing coverage report for a component MyCheckbox.js.

[coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC5hK.png)

How do I test the onCheckmarkPress() function in MyCheckbox.js?

Here is the implementation of MyCheckbox.js:

```html
import * as React from 'react';

import { Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useState } from 'react';

/**
 *
 * @param {() => void} props.onUpdate called when checkbox is pressed
 * @return {JSX.Element}
 * @constructor
 */
const MyCheckbox = (props) => {
  const [checked, onChange] = useState(false);
  function onCheckmarkPress() {
    onChange((prev) => {
      let checked = !prev;
      props.onUpdate(checked);
      return checked;
    });
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.checkboxBase, checked && styles.checkboxChecked]}
      onPress={onCheckmarkPress}
    >
      {checked && <Ionicons name="checkmark" size={24} color="black" />}
    </Pressable>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  checkboxBase: {
    width: 35,
    height: 35,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  checkboxChecked: {
    backgroundColor: '#C4C4C4',
  },
});

export default MyCheckbox;
```

This is how I attempt the test case:

```js
import React from 'react'
import MyCheckbox from '../MyCheckbox';
import {fireEvent, render, screen} from "@testing-library/react-native";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

it("works", () => {
    const onUpdateMock = jest.fn();
    render(<MyCheckbox onUpdate={onUpdateMock} />);

    expect(onUpdateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    expect(screen.queryByTestId("checkIcon")).toBeNull();

    const pressable = screen.getByRole("pressable");
    fireEvent.press(pressable);

    expect(onUpdateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(screen.queryByTestId("checkIcon")).toBeInTheDocument(); // check that the icon is rendered
});
```

However, I am getting the error "Unable to find an element with accessibilityRole: pressable". And will this cover the red lines marked in the coverage report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test the behaviour of your component, so it would look sth like this:

1. Render the component
2. Find the `Pressable` component
3. Make sure that `check` icon is not displayed
4. emulate the `click` event on `Pressable` component or other event (touch?) it responds to
5. Check if `check` icon is displayed

This kind of test will give you the coverage and the functionality tested.
Please provide the `Pressable` source if you need more detailed answer, it is hard to tell if it is button or some other implementation.

You can use the [React Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) to achieve all of above steps.

Assuming your `MyCheckbox` works like this:

```
const MyCheckbox = (props) => {
  const [checked, onChange] = React.useState(false);

  const onCheckmarkPress = () => {
    onChange((prev) => {
      let checked = !prev;
      props.onUpdate(checked);
      return checked;
    })
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={onCheckmarkPress}>
      {checked && <IonIcon data-testid="checkIcon" name="checkmark" />}
    </button>
  );
};
```

You could test it like this:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import MyCheckBox from "../MyCheckbox";

it("should work", () => {
  const onUpdateMock = jest.fn();
  render(<MyCheckBox onUpdate={onUpdateMock} />);
  expect(screen.queryByTestId("checkIcon")).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // check that the icon is not rendered
  const btn = screen.getByRole("button"); // get the button (pressable)
  fireEvent.click(btn); // click it

  expect(screen.getByTestId("checkIcon")).toBeInTheDocument(); // check that the icon is displayed
  expect(onUpdateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // make sure that the onUpdate function that was passed via props was clicked
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I updated my question and did a similar test case but encountered a new error.

Comment: I missed that this is`react-native`, sorry. There is no role like "pressable" so you need to find this element in different way. The easiest would be to add `data-testid` to that element like I did with the icon element. In your case the `pressable` element does not contain anything so it is hard to find it. I hope user can see it in UI ;) One more hint - use the `query` methods to find elements that you expect to not be in the document and `get` methods to find elements that should be in the document.

Comment: Thanks Marek, those are really helpful hints. Solved all the issues by adding a testID in the Pressable element.